# Why I can scrape dynamic website on my local computer using selenium but not on Google Colab?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use selenium in google colab to scrape the comments of YouTube video, but the script call the exception. When I run that same script on my local machine it works. The YouTube video website is dynamic, and I find that the return page source content doesn't return the full content on colab. However, I don't know how to figure it out.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

options = Options()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--window-size=2560x1440")
options.add_argument("start-maximised")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIYKR4sgzI8')

time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 500);')
time.sleep(10)

comment_div=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comments=comment_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')

for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)

driver.close()
```

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="contents"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.87)
```

Comment: google collab ips might be blocked by the website

Comment: Looking at your script you may need to "wait" longer for the element to appear. Or the element may not be appearing for numerous other reasons. my guess is that in google colab this page is blocked or is being shown differently than you're local instance.